# Ant: How to avoid SSH passwords?

Tags: macos, ant, ssh, exec, scp

### Problem

- We have a server over which we have FULL control
- We have a long, complicated shell script that interacts with this server via SCP and SSH
- We have an Ant Target that runs the script

simplified example:

```
<target name="run-script">
    <exec executable="/path/to/script_that_runs_ssh_cmds.sh" />
</target>
```

This target fails with the following exception:

```
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
```

### Question

After researching a bit, I think this can be fixed by generating public/private key pairs.  That way, the ssh command doesn't have to prompt for passwords.  Assuming this solution will work, how do you go about making it so that SSH calls on the system use keys in lieu of prompting for passwords?  Is it possible to set this up in a way that anyone on our team can run the Ant target successfully from their laptop?

Note: We're all running OS X 10.6 (Leopard) and physically connected to the same LAN as the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just install the private key under `~/.ssh` and `ssh` will automatically look into that directory and use the key you installed.

In the server side, add the public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Yep.  I followed these instructions and it worked PERFECTLY! [SSH w/o PWD](http://www.csua.berkeley.edu/~ranga/notes/ssh_nopass.html) . . . now I have another problem: my co-workers script SSH's over as root. Making this thing work as a "normal" user was straight-forward but how do you do the same thing as root?  I copied /home/userName/.ssh to /root/.ssh and it didn't work... (meaning when I SSH as userName@server, it doesn't require a PWD but when I use root@server, it does). Note: the server is RedHat

Comment: Is it necessary to SSH as root? It would be better if you change the script to SSH as a regular user. Not to mention remote root login is normally disabled.

Comment: I'd prefer not to but they're saying it's necessary because the script is running privileged commands. Remote login is not disabled for us (we have full control over the Linux server). My goal is to remove user interaction from this process (so I can run it from our Ant files) and I can't think of a way to modify their script such that it doesn't prompt for passwords when running elevated commands (plus the script is long and complicated yet 100% working)... so for now, I have to SSH as root :(

Comment: In that case, did you install the public key in the `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote server? Take a look at [this](http://nixcraft.com/getting-started-tutorials/429-mini-how-how-configure-ssh-keys-linux.html)